# Oracle database - copying objects to remote database and modifying so they use the remote database only if the local database is offline

Tags: sql, database, oracle, offline

I'm new to the forum and am studying Oracle SQL and PL/SQL.  I have created a local database and a database link to a remote database to which I have to copy all my objects.

I think I'll be able to do the copying of the objects from local to remote database, but neither my course material nor my googling have given me much of a steer in terms of the modifying the objects to use the remote tables only if the local database is offline.

I'd be hugely grateful if anyone has done a similar task and could point me in the direction of any good material on the subject.

(I'm working with Oracle 11g Express and Oracle SQL Developer)

Many thanks in advance

Edit from original poster:
I got some clarification on the task requirement (see comments below) and I've created a new thread to ask my next question about creating packages at the remote database end.  thanks guys for your help so far.

Comment: Are you saying that you want the code running in the remote database to connect back to your local database normally but to then fall back on the data in the remote database?  Even assuming that you could work out the networking aspects (I'd be surprised if you could create a database link in the school's remote database that connects back to your local database and there would be significant networking challenges if you have the appropriate privileges) that doesn't seem like a sensible architecture.  If you're just learning PL/SQL, it's way, way more complicated than you'd want to get.

Answer (score 0):

If database A is offline, a database link from database A to database B will not do you any good, as it will not be accessible. The same is the case with PL/SQL, PL/SQL on database A will not be available if database A is down. This is not a problem you will solve with PL/SQL and database links.
Transparent Application Failover (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/ocitaf.htm) could solve part of the problem, allowing a connection to failover to database B if database A is down. However, it will not automatically switch back to database A when the database comes back up, unless you try a connection to database A again. You will need to have your PL/SQL code copied on both databases.

There are already robust failover mechanisms in Oracle, some free and required some hacking, such as redo log application, some costly but well supported, such as Oracle Data Guard. I would suggest you review your design and what you are trying to accomplish. If I had to absolutely do what you are trying to do, I would throw a web service in front of each database, use a load balancer  in front of the web services that always connected to service A, unless it was down, in which case it would connect to service B.

Comment: many thanks Justin and Tony - you've backed up what I thought which was that a task like this sounds beyond the scope of the course I'm doing.  I've asked the course admin to confirm what the requirement is (they're a bit in and out when it comes to replying - it's distance learning, but hopefully I'll get a useful response).  I'll post back once I've heard something.

Comment: turns out the requirement is in fact to modify all the non-table objects on the remote database that reference tables (i.e. views etc), so that the objects on the remote database will reference the local tables unless the local database is offline, in which case they will reference the tables stored on the remote database.